# WebClient.DownloadFile and HTTPS + SharePoint 2007

Tags: ssl, document-library, document

I am trying to download a file (.docx) from 1 SharePoint 2007 library with `webclient.downloadfile()`. SharePoint Webapp has SSL enabled. I get "401 Unauthorized" exception when trying to download the file.

Is it even possible to use webclient with SSL?

Resolution for this might be to use copy.asmx "ootb" webservice to download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.

http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html

CookieAwareWebClient did the trick...